# r shiny - display multiple data tables on a page

Tags: r, shiny, record-linkage

I am trying to create an app in `R` `shiny`.  The first thing I would like to do is select two csv files to display on a page.  According to this:  https://community.rstudio.com/t/creating-tables-in-r-shiny-dynamically/14586 I need to add a `dataTableOutput` for each table in the `UI` and another `renderDataTable` in my `server`.  However, the app doesn't work when I tried that.

The code below only allows the user to load ONE csv file.

```
X <- c("plyr", "dplyr", "tm", "wordcloud", "SnowballC", "stringdist", "tidytext",
   "rmarkdown", "knitr", "quanteda", "qdap", "reshape", "stringr", "RecordLinkage", 
   "data.table", "rvest", "shiny", "shinydashboard", "DT")
lapply(X, FUN = function(X){
  do.call("library", list(X))
})
```

**UI**

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Record Linkage App"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
  ## Tab 1 -- Specify Task
  menuItem("Select Task And Upload Files", tabName = "task", icon = icon("file-text-o")),
  ## Tab 2 -- View Raw Data Files
  menuItem("View Raw Data", tabName = "raw", icon = icon("file-text-o")),
  ## Tab 3 -- View Processed Data Files
  menuItem("View Processed Data", tabName = "processed", icon = icon("file-text-o")),
  ## Tab 4 -- Select Training Set
  menuItem("Select Training Set", tabName = "mltrain", icon = icon("file-text-o")),
  ## Tab 5 -- View Weight & Probabilities (choose which chart to view or both?)
  menuItem("Visualize Distributions", tabName = "distributions", icon = icon("bar-chart-o")),
  ## Tab 6 -- View Results (review, match and trash files--need to be able to choose dataset)
  ## Want to be able to add checkboxes to select rows for inclusion in deletion later on
  menuItem("View Result Files", tabName = "fileview", icon = icon("file-text-o"))

)), # close dashboard sidebar

  #### Dashboard Body starts here

  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
  ### Specify Task & Upload Files Tab
  tabItem(tabName = "task",
          radioButtons("task", "Select a Task:", c("Frame Deduplication", "Frame Record Linkage")),
          fileInput("selection", "Upload Files:", multiple = T, 
                    accept = c(".xls", "text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values, text/plain", ".csv")),
          helpText(paste("Please upload a file.  Supported file types are:  .txt, .csv and .xls.")),
          helpText(paste("Note:  Record Linkage requires two data frames."))

          ), # close first tabItem

  tabItem(tabName = "raw",
          helpText(paste("This tab displays the raw, unprocessed data frames selected in the previous tab.")),
          helpText(paste("Select the columns you wish to display.  These columns will be used for string comparisons")),
            dataTableOutput("contents"),
            dataTableOutput("contents")
          )

) # close tabItems
  ) # close dashboardBody
) #close dashboardpage
options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 100*1024^2)
```

**SERVER**

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$contents <- renderDataTable({
    req(input$selection)
    #browser()
    read.csv(input$selection$datapath)

  })

  output$contents <- renderDataTable({
req(input$selection)
#browser()
read.csv(input$selection$datapath)

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I would like to:

1. Be able to upload multiple files
2. Choose the columns from each file to display (`checkboxInput`?)

Any help would be truly appreciated.

Comment: (Side comment: use of `"require"` without checking the return value is bad practice: if it isn't available, do something! I'd suggest you either use `"library"` (which will `stop` if not installed) or capture the return value and do something. That "something" might be `install.packages` or perhaps return a more meaningful error message within the shiny interface (I'd recommend the latter). A third option (much less common) is to have alternate functions available if a specific package is not available, typically only meaningful if the package is for code-speed.)

Comment: fair point.  I was using "require" because a while ago "library" wasn't working, but I agree it is better practice to use "library".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some changes to your code. Instead of `checkboxInput` I opted for the `pickerInput` from the `shinyWidgets` package (I added that to your code). Displaying two tables on the same page is already a lot of content, adding `checkboxInputs` on top of that would take up even more space. The pickerInput is light weight and nice and easy to use.

It is working here, please check it out and let me know if you have any trouble.

You probably need to configure how you want CSVs to be read in, especially the `sep` argument.

Note that reading multiple files with fileInput doesn't work in the RStudio pane or old Browsers such as IE 9.

**Update:** now allows to read in excel files with readxl and arranges the two table in columns next to each other.

```
X <- c("plyr", "dplyr", "tm", "readxl", "wordcloud", "SnowballC", "stringdist", "tidytext",
           "rmarkdown", "knitr", "quanteda", "reshape", "stringr", "RecordLinkage", 
           "data.table", "rvest", "qdap", "shiny", "shinydashboard", "shinyWidgets", "DT") 

lapply(X, FUN = function(X){
      do.call("library", list(X))
})

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Record Linkage App"),
    dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
            ## Tab 1 -- Specify Task
            menuItem("Select Task And Upload Files", tabName = "task", icon = icon("file-text-o")),
            ## Tab 2 -- View Raw Data Files
            menuItem("View Raw Data", tabName = "raw", icon = icon("file-text-o")),
            ## Tab 3 -- View Processed Data Files
            menuItem("View Processed Data", tabName = "processed", icon = icon("file-text-o")),
            ## Tab 4 -- Select Training Set
            menuItem("Select Training Set", tabName = "mltrain", icon = icon("file-text-o")),
            ## Tab 5 -- View Weight & Probabilities (choose which chart to view or both?)
            menuItem("Visualize Distributions", tabName = "distributions", icon = icon("bar-chart-o")),
            ## Tab 6 -- View Results (review, match and trash files--need to be able to choose dataset)
            ## Want to be able to add checkboxes to select rows for inclusion in deletion later on
            menuItem("View Result Files", tabName = "fileview", icon = icon("file-text-o"))

        )), # close dashboard sidebar

    #### Dashboard Body starts here

    dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
            ### Specify Task & Upload Files Tab
            tabItem(tabName = "task",
                    radioButtons("task", "Select a Task:", c("Frame Deduplication", "Frame Record Linkage")),
                    fileInput("selection", "Upload Files:", multiple = T, 
                              accept = c(".xlsx", ".xls", "text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values, text/plain", ".csv")),
                    helpText(paste("Please upload a file.  Supported file types are:  .txt, .csv and .xls.")),
                    helpText(paste("Note:  Record Linkage requires two data frames."))

            ), # close first tabItem

            tabItem(tabName = "raw",
                    helpText(paste("This tab displays the raw, unprocessed data frames selected in the previous tab.")),
                    helpText(paste("Select the columns you wish to display.  These columns will be used for string comparisons")),
                    fluidRow(
                        column(width = 6,
                               uiOutput("pick_col1"),
                               dataTableOutput("content1")
                               ),
                        column(width = 6,
                               uiOutput("pick_col2"),
                               dataTableOutput("content2")
                               )
                    )

        ) # close tabItem
    ) # close tabItems
) # close dashboardBody 
) # closes dashboardpage
options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 100*1024^2)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

    data <- reactiveValues(file1 = NULL,
                           file2 = NULL)

    observe({
        if (!is.null(input$selection$datapath[1]))

            if (grepl(".csv$", input$selection$datapath[1])) {

                data$file1 <- read.csv(input$selection$datapath[1], header = TRUE, sep = ";")

            } else if (grepl(".xls$|.xlsx$", input$selection$datapath[1])) {

                data$file1 <- read_excel(input$selection$datapath[1], col_names = TRUE)    
            } 
    })

    observe({
        if (!is.null(input$selection$datapath[2]))

            if (grepl(".csv$", input$selection$datapath[2])) {

                data$file2 <- read.csv(input$selection$datapath[2], header = TRUE, sep = ";")

            } else if (grepl(".xls$|.xlsx$", input$selection$datapath[2])) {

                data$file2 <- read_excel(input$selection$datapath[2], col_names = TRUE)    
            } 
    })

    output$pick_col1 <- renderUI({

        pickerInput(
            inputId = "pick_col1",
            label = "Select the columns of table 1 you wish to display:",
            choices = colnames(data$file1),
            selected = colnames(data$file1),
            options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE,
                           `selected-text-format` = paste0("count > ", length(colnames(data$file1)) - 1),
                           `count-selected-text` = "Alle",
                           liveSearch = TRUE,
                           liveSearchPlaceholder = TRUE),   # build buttons for collective selection
            multiple = TRUE)
    })

    output$pick_col2 <- renderUI({

        pickerInput(
            inputId = "pick_col2",
            label = "Select the columns of table 2 you wish to display:",
            choices = colnames(data$file2),
            selected = colnames(data$file2),
            options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE,
                           `selected-text-format` = paste0("count > ", length(colnames(data$file2)) - 1),
                           `count-selected-text` = "Alle",
                           liveSearch = TRUE,
                           liveSearchPlaceholder = TRUE),   # build buttons for collective selection
            multiple = TRUE)
    })



    output$content1 <- renderDataTable({

        data$file1[, req(input$pick_col1)]


    })

    output$content2 <- renderDataTable({

        data$file2[, req(input$pick_col2)]

    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: is there a way for the tables to be next to one another?  Ideally I would like to look at the contents of both at one time, and stacking them makes that kind of difficult.

Comment: This is no problem. You can do it with fluidRow(column(...),column(...)). I will update my answer later accordingly.

Comment: Thanks.  I was also wondering if `readxl` could also be conditionally incorporated?  For example, if the file uploaded were .xls instead of .csv how would the app know?

Comment: This is amazing!  Thanks so much!  I  had been struggling to put the two together, I am very new to shiny.  This will definitely help me understand the functionality a lot better.  I will award bounty as soon as I am able

Comment: I have been trying to apply a user defined function to the selected columns of both tables, via wrapping the function around the `output$content1`, i.e. `function(data$file1[, req(input$pick_col1)` but I get errors every time.  Do you know why?

Comment: Can you give a simplified example of the function you want to use on the data in the output expression? As pointed out in my other answer you commented on, using a reactive expression instead of a custom function might also work. Or you could transform the data in the output expression.